# Add an element to an existing array in Typescript, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

-this is my saved list-

```
export const FORMULARLIST: formular[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Max Mustermann', mobileNumber: 123456, secondMobileNumber: 654321, email: 'MaxMustermann@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'MaxMustermannSecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A101', task: "Rechenzentrum" },];

-this is my interface-

export interface formular {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    mobileNumber: number;
    secondMobileNumber: number;
    email: string;
    secondEmail: string;
    roomNumber: string;
    task: string;
}

-And that is the function that should add an element to the array. What it does, but as soon as I put something in my box from my input field in the html file, the list changes too-

addNew(){
FORMULARLIST.push(this.formular);
}


-the button with the function-

<input (click)="addNew()" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
```

-The Html data with the input box-

```
 <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Aufgabe:</span>
            <input id="newtask" [(ngModel)]="formular.task" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Aufgabe" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

´´´
I don't know how to add one element without changing the other
´´´

Comment: The button should only be triggered when you click on it and it should use the function addNew (); carry out

Comment: How is your list changing when you enter some value? Is a new item getting added or the "task" property of the existing one's changes?

Comment: Yes, as soon as an element has been added and I want to add another one, it will be changed as soon as I write something new in the input field. That means the task field is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing a classic example of object mutation. The same `formular` object is being referenced by the added items of the array. That's why when you make changes in the main object, all the references also gets changed because in JS Objects are a reference type.

To avoid it, simply add a new `formular` object into your array

```
addNew(){
FORMULARLIST.push({...this.formular});
}
```

This way you are creating a new object and adding it in the array and `this.formular` references to the current object being edited.

**Note:** The above code uses [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a copy of object

Answer (score 0):

you can use a separate variable in the component (example => my_task:string;)
and in the template you can directly add  `[(ngModel)]=my_task;`

after that on button click you can do

```
addNew(){
FORMULARLIST.push({
 id: '';
name: '';
mobileNumber: 0;
secondMobileNumber: 0;
email: '';
secondEmail: '';
roomNumber: '';
task: string;
task:this.my_task
});
this.my_task = ''; // reset the input variable
}
```

is this the final result that you want ?